# NoUISlider with lowest and highest values shown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use NoUISlider... [NoUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/?ref=designsfree/)

It works great, but I cannot get both the lowest price AND the highest price shown when the user scrolls the handles. Somehow ONLY the € (highest price) changes the value regardless you scroll the left or right handle. Is it possible to get both lowest and highest price values shown when the left and right handles are used. I do not see where I am making the mistake.

Here my BOOTPLY... [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/nt92KuRZlj)

The FULL working code is in BOOTPLY, but below the relevant code where I think I made the mistake.

```js
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('slider-range');
noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
  start: [4000, 10000],
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': [2000],
    'max': [10000]
  }
});
var stepSliderValueElement = [
  document.getElementById('slider-range-lower'),
  document.getElementById('slider-range-upper')
];
rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  stepSliderValueElement.innerHTML = values[handle];
});
```

```html
<div class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background" id="slider-range"></div>
€ (lowest price) <span class="example-val" id="slider-range-lower"></span>
€ (highest price) <span class="example-val" id="slider-range-upper"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because `stepSliderValueElement` is an array of elements and you were trying to change the `.innerHTML` property of that array. You need to change the property of the element in the array correspinding to the value in the `values` array:

Since you're only changing the text based on the value(s), you can also use the `.textContent` property rather than `.innerHTML`:

[**Updated Example**](http://www.bootply.com/OszUOk4Vsh#)

```
rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  stepSliderValueElement[0].textContent = values[0];
  stepSliderValueElement[1].textContent = values[1];
});
```

---

Working Code:

```js
var rangeSlider = document.getElementById('slider-range');
noUiSlider.create(rangeSlider, {
  start: [4000, 10000],
  connect: true,
  range: {
    'min': [2000],
    'max': [10000]
  }
});
var stepSliderValueElement = [document.getElementById('slider-range-lower'),
  document.getElementById('slider-range-upper')
];

rangeSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
  stepSliderValueElement[0].textContent = values[0];
  stepSliderValueElement[1].textContent = values[1];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.js"></script>
<div class="noUi-target noUi-ltr noUi-horizontal noUi-background" id="slider-range"></div>
€ (lowest price) <span class="example-val" id="slider-range-lower"></span>
€ (highest price) <span class="example-val" id="slider-range-upper"></span>
```